# How to get started writing Perl bindings for a C++ library?

Tags: c++, perl, cpan

I want to write Perl bindings for a C++ library, so that the library can be used from Perl. How would I get started doing this? I've written pure-Perl modules for CPAN before.

Comment: [Swig++](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html) comes to mind

Comment: Last time I tried it, Swig generated such horrific code that I'm permanently scarred from looking at it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) and there [XS](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html). I used XS for [Net::Sharktools](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::Sharktools) which was the first time I wrote any XS code. I point to it because it was a particularly trivial case, and might be a good way to get an idea of what is involved.

[perldoc perlxs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html#Using-XS-With-C++) includes a section on C++ specific aspects as well.

Comment: Make sure to check out xsubpp's -hiertype option when dealing with C++ in XS.

Answer (score 6):

Binding a C++ library is a lot trickier that a C library, for a lot of reasons. Not in the last place because the standard toolchain is fairly C centric. [XSpp](https://metacpan.org/module/ExtUtils%3a%3aXSpp) is a lot more powerful that plain XS, though it has an additional learning curve.

I'd love to recommend my own [libperl++](https://github.com/Leont/libperl--) for this, but it's still very much in the alpha stage.

Comment: What Leon said. For XS++ (XSpp) my slides from YAPC in Pisa may be useful: http://steffen-mueller.net/talks/xspp/ XS++ examples include in order of complexity: Math::ThinPlateSpline, Math::Clipper, Wx

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention 'SOOT' as an example. But that's so weird that anybody learning from it would have to be more than a little insane. :)